# Explanation on how this code using web namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net

HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;

In the above example, why do we cast sender to a HTTPApplication and not HTTPContext?

Also, what is the purpose of the brackets? I know they are for casting, but if you get rid of HTTPApplication and the surrounding brackets, that leaves:

```
(sender).Context;
```

Why not sender.Context? Or generically, why the use of brackets anyway? I vaguely remember it is a way of casting but can't remember specifics.

Secondly:

```
 string url = context.Request["url"];
 int cacheDuration = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["cache"] ?? "0");
 string contentType = context.Request["type"];
```

EDIT: I realised that you can write:

```
collection["key"] = "value";
```

This is for a key-based collection and you store value where there is a key called "key". So am I right in thinking you get the url where the key is "url"?

I know this is using HTTPContext, but in the indexer, what is "url" meant to mean? It is just a string saying url, not even a real url. Likewise for "cache" and "type". If one writes "type", as in the last line of code, does that get back the type (HTTP/HTTPS) used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to cast `sender` to `HttpApplication` because (presumably) that's the actual type - it then *gets* an `HttpContext` via the `HttpApplication.Context` property.

Given that, you *do* need the cast, therefore the bracketing is reasonable.

For the second part: `"url"`, `"cache"` and `"type"` are just the names of request parameters (which are [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) to come from the cookies, form submission, server variables or URL query parameters). So the original URL might be:

> http://server.com/Foo.aspx?url=someurl&cache=10&type=text/plain

... or the values could come from cookies etc. I would hope that given that information, it would be clear where they'd *really* come from in this case :)

Comment: Apologies for clarity. I couldn't get the code to be presented in its code view. Anyway, I won't edit at the same time such to prevent data corruption! :)

Comment: That link covers everything perfectly.

Thanks!